# Copy files from multiple folders with including folder name in Linux

Tags: linux, file, directory, cp, file-manipulation

I have multiple sub folders e.g.:

```
ls ./
F1 F2 F5 F8 F12 ...
```

Each folder contain file "file.txt"

How to copy all file.txt files to main folder containing folder name?

```
cp ./F1/file.txt ./file_1.txt
cp ./F2/file.txt ./file_2.txt
...
```

Answer (score 2):

**Perl One Liner**

first go to main folder than:

`find . | perl -a -F/ -lne 'qx(cp -r "$F[1]" T/ )'`

**note**
do not worry about log file on the screen if would be!
**T/**
is your target directory
**main folder**
Where all your file exist.  If your all file is in the folder **Music** for example; so `cd Music` then that *Perl One Liner*

Answer (score 1):

```
declare -a dirs
i=1
for d in */
do
    dirs[i++]="${d%/}"
done
echo "There are ${#dirs[@]} dirs in the current path"

for((i=1;i<=${#dirs[@]};i++))
do
    echo "Copying file.txt from ${dirs[i]} dir..."
    cp ./${dirs[i]}/file.txt ./file_$i.txt
done
```

Save it as a script file, `fileTxtCopy.sh`, for instance. Then place it at the parent dir and give it executable permission `sudo chmod +x fileTxtCopy.sh`.

Run it as script and you should have all your `file.txt` file copied in parent dir.

Answer (score 0):

Copies `file.txt` files from each folder inside a current directory to the current directory and appends numbers contained in a folder name to the name of the copied file.

```
for i in *; do a=$(<<< "$i" grep -o "[0-9]*" -); cp "$i/file.txt" "file_$a.txt"; done
```

Not the most robust approach though.